# pthread_setschedparam returns EPERM even for root user

Tags: c++, multithreading, kernel

I am chasing a problem with pthread_setschedparam that recently popped up.
I have a C++ program that calls pthread_setschedparam to set round-robin scheduling ( SCHED_RR ).
The call fails, returning EPERM, even when run as the root user(!)
I am running under the linux kernel version 4.1.6 ( recently upgraded ).
Could this kernel version have a bug  that causes this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Was the kernel version the *only* thing that changed?

Comment: Yes.    But I found that the following command "fixes" the problem:

Comment: echo -1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us

Comment: This is odd since it basically means the real time scheduling policies have unlimited time (?)